# Entity framework not creating insert statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Wonder if you could help me with something I have been scratching my head for some time with.  I'll begin with the code first!

```
public class DevelopmentImageContext : Context<DevelopmentImage>
{
    public List<DevelopmentImage> DevelopmentImages { get; private set; }

    public DevelopmentImageContext() { }

    public DevelopmentImageContext(int imageId)
    {
        EntityId = imageId;
    }

    public DevelopmentImageContext(Development development)
    {
        var result = (from d in Context.DevelopmentImages
                      where d.Development == development
                      select d).ToList();
        DevelopmentImages = result;
    }

    public override DevelopmentImage GetEntity()
    {
        if (EntityId != 0)
        {
            return Context.DevelopmentImages.Where(d => d.ImageId == EntityId).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        throw new EntityNotFound("Entity was either null or 0");
    }

    public override void CreateEntity(DevelopmentImage entity)
    {
        Context.DevelopmentImages.AddObject(entity);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override void CreateEntities(List<DevelopmentImage> entities)
    {
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            try
            {
                Context.DevelopmentImages.AddObject(entity);
                CommitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to create Object", exception);
            }

        }
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

There is a abstract class called ContextManager with a property called Context.  I can post this if necessary.

When calling the CreateEntities method, I pass through a list of Development, loop through them and insert into the database.  Problem is, nothing is created.  Tried using EFProf to see if it creates a transaction with the insert query and nothing.  I do have another method in the Context class called DeleteEntities which effectly deletes all the data in the data using some basic SQL and the ExecuteStoreCommand method.  Within EFProf I can see this SQL being executed.

Any ideas why I cannot create the object?

Thanks,
Matt

Edit: I have renamed the property Context to ContextEntity to see if this changes anything and no :(

Comment: I have even tried ContextEntity.AddToDevelopments(entity); with no joy

Comment: Does `CreateEntity` for a single entity work? And what is `CommitChanges()`?

Comment: I have a further update on this; talking directly to the Business layer works with no problems at all.  I am trying to implement a service and this service when talking to the Business Layer isn't creating a statement to execute.  Is there anything special I have to do to the service layer to get it to create a database connection?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide details (much more people will notice a change in the question than a comment) and explain what you mean with "talking *directly* to the Business layer" in contrast to a "service ... talking to the Business layer".

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your db connection string? Since you are using code first, it is probably creating a new database and everything seems to work fine. Best to provide the connection string explicitly.

If you happen to have no configuration file, a default database will be used:

> Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial
>   Catalog=MyNamespace.MyContext;Integrated
>   Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True

To find out:

```
using (BlogContext context = new BlogContext())
{                             
   string cs = context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: Connection to the database is fine - I can see it is quering the database but not creating the insert statements...

Comment: I recommend to investigate the object context just before the savechanges call. Are all objects in it with state added? You can do this by calling ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738497.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I feel massivly stupid.  I sould have posted the ContextManager class because someone would have spoted my mistake:

```
    private static GirlingsWebEntities _entity;

    public GirlingsWebEntities ContextEntity
    {
        get
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current == null)
            {
                return _entity ?? (_entity = new GirlingsWebEntities());
            }
            else
            {
                string sKey = "context_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x");
                if (!HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains(sKey))
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add(sKey, new GirlingsWebEntities());
                    ((GirlingsWebEntities)HttpContext.Current.Items[sKey]).ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
                }
                return (GirlingsWebEntities)HttpContext.Current.Items[sKey];
            }

        }
    }

    public void CommitChanges()
    {
        ContextEntity.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

where I have return _entity ?? (_entity = new GirlingsWebEntities()); I was just returning a normal property and not a static property so therefore using a different connection to the database, one that didn't exist!

Hope this helps someone else out :)